# Производительность ресурса

Tags: oracle-apex

создал в Oracle Apex - RestAPI с методом post .
При обращение получаю входные параметры , обращаюсь к пакету в своей базе данных и собираю из выходных данных пакета xml . Но пользователей не устраивает быстродействие ресурса . Сейчас выходная xml из 200 строк собирается от 5 и больше секунд . Может кто знает какие то настройки для более быстрой работы .
В json собрать не может , пользователи принимают только xml (

Comment: 5 секунд 200 строк xml? у меня на продакшине сотни тысяч строк генерируються за такое же к-ство времени. У вас очень много времени идет на формирование выходных данных, а не на генерации xml. Советую сделать какое-либо кеширование этих данных, чтобы при одинаковом запросе не стучаться каждый раз к базе

Comment: @ВадимАлександру К сожалению , пока я не знаю как настроить кеширование . Можете подсказать как это сделать ?

Comment: Так же , отключил клиента , который по видимому парсил нас и ответ собирается уже за 1207 мс . 
Если кто знает какие настройки по кол-ву подключений к ресурсу или наподобие .